# Is there a way to make Apple Emoji display correctly?

Tags: keyboard, messaging

My wife and mother love to send me texts from their iPhones full of Emoji characters.

How can I make this display correctly?
Usually it ends up looking like this:

"Hey, how are you doing? "
and "Want to play Bejewelled? "

Comment: Is that in the Messaging Hub? And are those the actual emoji?

Comment: They are actual Emoji. Added to the question from an iPhone.

Comment: get them a windows phone ;-)

Comment: "Hey, how are you doing? " and "Want to play Bejewelled? " Works fine for me on the Lumia 800 and iPhone 4, the only difference seems to be that they are coloured on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless they send one that is compatible with the phone, it won't be displayed properly. Sorry, but not everything is going to be compatible across devices.

Certain ones will work fine...like smiles. Others won't. Perhaps there is a 3rd party messaging app that will do it better. You will lose right integration with the phone though.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 does support a large set of Unicode 6.0 emojis.

You can get a good idea of which Unicode emojis are supported by your phone by visiting the [emoji Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Emoji_in_the_Unicode_standard) in your phone's browser.

I was able to send/receive an SMS containing emojis from the *Apple Encoding\Objects* section to an iPhone with no problems.

Comment: That page seems to suggest that the iPhones need to be running iOS v5 for compatibility with WP7.